# Extract data from graph with curve as axis

Tags: charts, axis

I need to get data from a pretty simple yet not really common type of plot (graph). If you take a look at this image, you will notice that the Y axis is irrelevant and that curve has to take its place.

[image]

The actual data I need is `for each 'X'(l) read value of t(l)`.

I've already tried UN-SCAN-IT, Engauge, Digitizeit etc. and none of them seems to support curves as an axis – or maybe I'm going about this issue the wrong way.

Comment: Ok, didnt seem that way at first, so far 6 programs were tested by me and non seem to produce any results thats why I posted similar question.

Comment: I can not understand what you are trying to do!  
What do you mean by t[1]? 
You have a graph in which, the horizontal axis represents the distance travelled, in KM, and the vertical axis shows the speed, in KM/h.  
The curve gives you different speeds at different travelled distances.

Comment: Its not like that, curve gives time in seconds needed for travel, I had some progress with Dagra, I will post answer when Im satisfied with results (main thing I need here is how much is for example t(1,1) on X axis. While reading 1 2 3 4 ... 13 is easy values in-between are not.